# Neo4j enterprise edition 1.8.3 (embedded) online backup using Java

Tags: java, neo4j, database-backups

I am using Neo4j 1.8.3 enterprise edition. I tried to do the online backup using Java like below

```
val backupPath: File = new File("D:/neo4j-enterprise-1.8.3/data/backup/")
val backup = OnlineBackup.from( "127.0.0.1" )
if(backupPath.list().length > 0)
{
    backup.incremental( backupPath.getPath() , false )
}
else
{
    backup.full( backupPath.getPath() );
}
```

Since the backups are enabled by default only after the version 1.9 I added the line below to the neo4j properties file

```
# Port to listen to for incoming backup requests.
online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362
```

I am able to do backup with Neo4j 1.9.4 enterprise edition. But, I got the exception below when I tried the same with Neo4j 1.8.3 enterprise edition.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.neo4j.com.ComException: Client could not connect to /127.0.0.1:6362
    at org.neo4j.com.Client$1.create(Client.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.com.Client$1.create(Client.java:101)
    at org.neo4j.com.ResourcePool.acquire(ResourcePool.java:104)
    at org.neo4j.com.Client.getChannel(Client.java:304)
    at org.neo4j.com.Client.sendRequest(Client.java:191)
    at org.neo4j.com.Client.sendRequest(Client.java:180)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupClient.fullBackup(BackupClient.java:50)
    at org.neo4j.backup.BackupService.doFullBackup(BackupService.java:98)
    at org.neo4j.backup.OnlineBackup.full(OnlineBackup.java:57)
    at Saddahaq.User_node$.backup_data(User_node.scala:1652)
    at Saddahaq.User_node$.main(User_node.scala:2313)
    at Saddahaq.User_node.main(User_node.scala)
    at Saddahaq.Fun.main(Fun.java:16)
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you check the manual? http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.8.3/operations-backup.html esp. online_backup_port=9999.

Comment: online_backup_enabled=true , online_backup_server=127.0.0.1:6362 . I added these 2 lines in the neo4j properties file as per the manual. But, am still getting the same error